# How to conditionally set root view controller for a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I have a navigation controller which should have a different root depending on the state of my App.

How can i model this within Interface Builder? I've dragged out a `UINavigationController` to my Storyboard. Now I need to make the connections to the two view controllers.

Sadly I can only set one as root view controller. Do i need to subclass the Navigation Controller and based on the state reset the root view controller?

What is the best practise for this kind of problem? It would be nice to visualize this relationship within Interface Builder.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As it is the rootViewController you want to change conditionally, you could have two navigationControllers (each with the different rootViewControllers), and present the correct one (navigationController) based on your condition.

Comment: That will be good if you implement this programatically. With Setting rootviewcontrollers programmatically.

Comment: You have one viewcontroller embedded in a navigation controller. Based on some condition (which?), you segue to one of two possible controllers. How is this action made? Button?

Comment: @marius: I actually have a tabbar controller. The first tab is a view controller which is embedded into a navigation controller. However for simplicity let's say if a Boolean value is set to true the embedded view controller needs to be a differend one. I hope I could make myself clear. Maybe I should make a seperate navigation controller which embedds the other one and replace the first tab of the tab bar controller instead.

Comment: I just relized that I want to switch the root and not segue. Edited the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: Did any of the answers to this question help you?

Answer (score 4):

As it is the rootViewController you want to change conditionally, you could instead have two different navigationControllers, each with the one of the two different viewControllers as its rootViewController.

You could then present the appropriate navigationController based on your condition.

Answer (score 1):

Have two segues (one to viewcontrollerA  and the other to viewcontrollerB). The your Navigation Controller would determine the App state and call performSegue to move the user to the correct view controller.

Comment: What about root view controller don't i need to set one for the navigation controller ?